# Eliminate duplicates on fetching data from multiple tables

Tags: sql

Fetching data from three tables a , b, c . first table have the company name , second table is the category and third table is location table.
For eg:-

This is the result I get :-

```
a        b             c
xx     electrical      us
yy      IT             uk
zz      mech           IND 
xx      IT             IND
xx      electrical     uk


mySQL =  "select  a.*, b.*, c.* from a_tbl a  left join b_tbl b on      a.S_ID = b.CAT_ID left join c_tbl c on a.location=c.location_id where a.status <> '0' "&sql&" order by a.name"
```

The above code is working fine and fetching all the data . I want the duplicates to be removed  . This is the result i expect

```
 a        b             c
xx     electrical      us
yy      IT             uk
zz      mech           IND
```

How can I modify ???

Comment: Those are not duplicate tuples. The requirements are underspecified.

Comment: yes .. i want distinct company names to be fetched .

Comment: That output contains columns that are not caught in the duplicate check - they are not duplicate tuples. This cannot be solved with the expected output without more details on how the final records should be selected.

Comment: First table "a_tbl" have columns like company name ,category,category_id, address , telphone , location , website . Second table "b_tbl" have columns like category_name , cat_id . third table have location_name and location_id .when executing the query , the final result should not repeat the company name . it need to be distinct

Comment: Then select from a with an added ordering column,  and from b,  likewise. Then union the queries,  group on the duplicate columns, and select the first record from each group based on the ordering column.

Comment: There are duplicates, for sure.

Comment: I will try to use union as u say ...

Comment: Even though you want distinct companies, which category and location out of multiple ones to choose from? Once you know the criteria many options are available: subqueries, derived tables, aggregate queries, etc.

Comment: can select any category and location ..but i want only one company name to be displayed ...